# VB Finding Pattern in filename

Tags: vb.net, filenames

I have 2 variables:

```
    Dim filename as string = "Test2020.csv"
    Dim fileSearch as string = "Test*.csv"
```

Filename is the name of the file and file search is the pattern that was used to find it.

I am in a situation where I need to check if the filename matches the pattern.

The way I was going to do it is take every string before the *: "Test" and everything after the *: ".csv" and check if the filename starts and ends with these. Is there an easier and simpler way to find if one string pattern matches the other.

Please note, I am comparing 2 strings and not trying to locate a file in a directory.

Comment: can you use a regex, or take the pattern given, and convert to a regex, then use?

Comment: Is it possible to tell me what the regex pattern will be. My knowledge on regex is low. I have used regex before but it was to remove spaces.

Comment: If `fileSearch` is the pattern used to find `filename`, why do you think the file name would not be a match (since it already has been matched)? Are you omitting some details?

Comment: @Jimi Yeah filename variable could be updated since the time its been found. I am stuck with a list file patterns and one file name. I need to find which file pattern it belongs to it. This is an existing company application so I am limited to how much I can change,

Comment: Try: `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(filename, "(?<=)Test\d{4}.csv", System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)`

Comment: For all things regex, I'd recommend having a look at [Regex Hero](http://regexhero.net).

It has both an online regex checker and a downloadable version. It'll help you learn the regex ropes, and there are quite a few user-submitted examples in its library.

I'm not associated with Regex Hero in any way other than I use it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

This returns true:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
Dim fileSearch As String = "Test1929.csv"
Dim FileNameMatch As Boolean = fileSearch Like "Test####[.]csv"
TextBox1.Text = FileNameMatch
End Sub
```

This returns false:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
Dim fileSearch As String = "Testabcd.csv"
Dim FileNameMatch As Boolean = fileSearch Like "Test####[.]csv"
TextBox1.Text = FileNameMatch
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.StartWith()` and `String.EndsWith()`.

```
Private Function TestPatternMatch(FileName As String) As Boolean
    If FileName.StartsWith("Test") AndAlso FileName.EndsWith(".csv") Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function
```

Usage:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Debug.Print(TestPatternMatch("Test2020.csv").ToString)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

VB.Net does have the LEGACY [Like Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/like-operator):

> Compares a string against a pattern.

You can't use it in `.NET Core` or `.NET Standard`, though:

> The Like operator is currently not supported in .NET Core and .NET
> Standard projects.

If that doesn't bother you, then here's an example:

```
Dim filename As String = "Test2020.csv"
Dim fileSearch As String = "Test*.csv"
If filename Like fileSearch Then
    Debug.Print("Passed the pattern test.")
Else
    Debug.Print("Did NOT pass the pattern test.")
End If
```